# CSS: Vertical align a image inside a div

Tags: html, css, xhtml, vertical-alignment

Is it possible to vertical align a image (variable height) in a div? And that it work in IE 7 and up? I know that it can be done with the display : table-cell but the table-cell is not supported in IE 7...

I hope somewone has a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #000;line-height:100px;">
   something in here
</div>​
```